# Breeze - Bug when saving graph of objects

Tags: breeze

<del>I have an error with this scenario:

Using NHibernate, GuidComb generator and latest pull from breeze(2eca9bdb90b7c74c42d45202707221f93371bcc1)  

Scenario: Create an entity which has a collection of other entities. Try to save everything in one shot.  

Result: The bug is in the id management. Breeze process the entities and build a SaveOrder. The parent Entity is saved(`NHContext.cs` line 201). Now, the id of the parent has changed from the temp guid generated by Breeze to the real guid used in the database. Then, when Breeze tries to save the children, I got a foreign key constraint error since the foreign key in the children contains the temp id and not the real id. I'm almost sure it was working with breeze 1.4.6. A lot of rewrite has been done in the NHibernate code.

I didn't try with others identity strategy, only GuidComb.

**edit**: <del>I have the same problem with Entity Framework 6 and 
`DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity`</del>. It's not the same kind problem with EF. I'll ask another question for that.  
**edit**: The temp guid are the same. It's only when the save is executed that the parent guid changes and not the children.</del>

---

Here's the right scenario:
An entity Document inherits from Material. A Material has a collection of MaterialSourceLanguage which is a many to many.

```
public class BaseEntity : IDeletable
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual int Version { get; set; }

    public virtual bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime? UpdateDate { get; set; }
}

public class Material : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual IList<MaterialSourceLanguage> SourceLanguages { get; set; }

    public Material()
    {
        this.SourceLanguages = new List<MaterialSourceLanguage>();
    }

}

public class Document : Material
{
    public virtual string FileName { get; set; }
}

public class MaterialSourceLanguage : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual Guid? MaterialId { get; set; }

    public virtual Material Material { get; set; }

    public virtual Guid? LanguageId { get; set; }

    public virtual Language Language { get; set; }

    public MaterialSourceLanguage()
    {
    }
}
```

If I create an entity `Document` and attach several `MaterialSourceLanguage` to it, the foreign key error occurs. why? 
In our case the real entity type is `Document`(type added in `AddToGraph`).
When `Breeze` executes `FindInSaveMap`(`NHRelationshipFixer.cs`) it doesn't find any entity of type `Material` in it.

I hope there is enough info?

**edit**: I made a workaround in `NHRelationshipFixer.cs`, it's enough for us right now:

```
private EntityInfo FindInSaveMap(Type entityType, object entityId)
    {
        var entityIdString = entityId.ToString();
        var entityInfoList = saveMap.Where(p => entityType.IsAssignableFrom(p.Key)).Select(p => p.Value).FirstOrDefault();
        if (entityInfoList != null)
        {
            var meta = session.SessionFactory.GetClassMetadata(entityType);
            foreach (var entityInfo in entityInfoList)
            {
                var entity = entityInfo.Entity;
                var id = meta.GetIdentifier(entity, EntityMode.Poco);
                if (id != null && entityIdString.Equals(id.ToString()))
                    return entityInfo;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I understand, but look at that [page](http://www.breezejs.com/support) and tell me where to contact them?

Comment: I don't blame NHibernate at all... but it's in the NHibernate provider  of breeze... I'll be more precise next time

Comment: If you examine the JSON sent from the client, do the parent and child entities share the same temporary GUID?  They should; that's how the server knows they are related.  I'm suspicious if both NH and EF have the same problem.

Comment: @radim I thoroughly disagree. I know what you're saying but maybe 50% of the questions on SO are expressed as "bugs" and 90% of those are really cries for help about "how to" rather than bugs proper. Maybe this is a bug, maybe not. Doesn't matter ... it fits here in SO just fine. No reason for you to be making up policy as you go.

Comment: @radim One more thing. Breeze is a free open source project. There is no "vendor".

Comment: @Inu, I'm not sure what's happening.  I have the same scenario in my NH test suite, using guid.comb, and it works fine.  Once the relationships are re-established on the server side, NH should take care of updating the foreign key values when they change.

Comment: Is the many-to-one relationship mapped on your child class?

Comment: Ok. I nailed it. First, saving a graph of objects works pretty well. I tested several scenarios and it works all the time. The problem here is that we have inheritance. I'm going to update the initial question to add more details.

Comment: Thanks @lnu.  I see the problem, and I'll put in your fix.

Comment: @lnu, I checked in the fix.  Slightly different from yours, to account for the case when (for example) both Document and Picture extend Material, and both Document and Picture appear in the SaveMap.  Please try it out let me know if it works for you.  Thanks for finding another one.

Comment: Ok. But it seems you modified the webapi v2 branch and not the old one we're currently using(Breeze.WebApi.NH).

Comment: Argh!  You're right, I forgot to update the WebApi 1 code.  Fixed now.